# AWS API Gateway Integration Response does not throws 409 error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am using AWS API gateway with a Lambda Integration. There is a scenario, where I want to throw an exception(python) and return a 409 HTTP status code. I added a Method response and an Integration response with a regex of the exception.
There is a wildcard for 500 error to handle any other errors.

Now, when i simulate the error scenario, I always get a 500, though the errorMessage field has the correct exception message which matches with the regex I provided.
Just to try out things, I modified the error code to 429. Surprisingly it works.

Is there a fixed list of error codes that we can throw from Integration Response or do we need to do something else to throw a 409 error.